# ODBC Driver List from .NET

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

Is there a way to get a list of ODBC drivers that are installed on a Windows XP machine from .NET?

I basically would like to see (in .NET) what is in:

> Control Panel->Administrative
>   Tools->Data Sources (ODBC)->"Drivers"
>   Tab.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

See [this](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/sdbODBCMngr.aspx) or [this](http://www.devtoolshed.com/content/get-list-odbc-data-source-names-programatically-using-c)

Basically system stores the ODBC Driver's information here
`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\ODBC\ODBCINST.INI\ODBC Drivers`

You can use this or similar code to find out the installed ODBC Drivers. This code basically reads the drivers info from registry

```
 public static List<String> GetSystemDriverList()
        {
            List<string> names = new List<string>();
            // get system dsn's
            Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey reg = (Microsoft.Win32.Registry.LocalMachine).OpenSubKey("Software");
            if (reg != null)
            {
                reg = reg.OpenSubKey("ODBC");
                if (reg != null)
                {
                    reg = reg.OpenSubKey("ODBCINST.INI");
                    if (reg != null)
                    {

                        reg = reg.OpenSubKey("ODBC Drivers");
                        if (reg != null)
                        {
                            // Get all DSN entries defined in DSN_LOC_IN_REGISTRY.
                            foreach (string sName in reg.GetValueNames())
                            {
                                names.Add(sName);
                            }
                        }
                        try
                        {
                            reg.Close();
                        }
                        catch { /* ignore this exception if we couldn't close */ }
                    }
                }
            }

            return names;
        }
```

Comment: It's a great answer, however, it will be nice if you used `using` when you get your registries. In case that it crashes, the memory will be cleaned.

Answer (score 21):

It is not necessary to open every intermediate subkey. Reading the registry key to get the ODBC driver names can be done in a much more compact fashion as follows:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the ODBC driver names from the registry.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>a string array containing the ODBC driver names, if the registry key is present; null, otherwise.</returns>
    public static string[] GetOdbcDriverNames()
    {
        string[] odbcDriverNames = null;
        using (RegistryKey localMachineHive = Registry.LocalMachine)
        using (RegistryKey odbcDriversKey = localMachineHive.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\ODBC\ODBCINST.INI\ODBC Drivers"))
        {
            if (odbcDriversKey != null)
            {
                odbcDriverNames = odbcDriversKey.GetValueNames();
            }
        }

        return odbcDriverNames;
    }
```

You can also implement the function by doing a P/Invoke to SQLGetInstalledDriversW:

```
    [DllImport("odbccp32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern bool SQLGetInstalledDriversW(char[] lpszBuf, ushort cbufMax, out ushort pcbBufOut);

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the ODBC driver names from the SQLGetInstalledDrivers function.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>a string array containing the ODBC driver names, if the call to SQLGetInstalledDrivers was successfull; null, otherwise.</returns>
    public static string[] GetOdbcDriverNames()
    {   
        string[] odbcDriverNames = null;
        char[] driverNamesBuffer = new char[ushort.MaxValue];
        ushort size;

        bool succeeded = SQLGetInstalledDriversW(driverNamesBuffer, ushort.MaxValue, out size);

        if (succeeded == true)
        {
            char[] driverNames = new char[size - 1];
            Array.Copy(driverNamesBuffer, driverNames, size - 1);
            odbcDriverNames = (new string(driverNames)).Split('\0');
        }

        return odbcDriverNames;
    }
```

I also call the function and use the results as follows to gracefully degrade to prior versions of the SQL driver when creating ODBC data sources:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the name of an ODBC driver for Microsoft SQL Server giving preference to the most recent one.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>the name of an ODBC driver for Microsoft SQL Server, if one is present; null, otherwise.</returns>
    public static string GetOdbcSqlDriverName()
    {
        List<string> driverPrecedence = new List<string>() { "SQL Server Native Client 11.0", "SQL Server Native Client 10.0", "SQL Server Native Client 9.0", "SQL Server" };
        string[] availableOdbcDrivers = GetOdbcDriverNames();
        string driverName = null;

        if (availableOdbcDrivers != null)
        {
            driverName = driverPrecedence.Intersect(availableOdbcDrivers).FirstOrDefault();
        }

        return driverName;
    }
```

Comment: So then why not simply `using (RegistryKey odbcDriversKey = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\ODBC\ODBCINST.INI\ODBC Drivers"))` ? :)

Comment: @VladL Object disposal. Referencing Registry.LocalMachine yields an object that implements IDisposable. It's good practice to make sure that .Dispose gets called when you are done rather than waiting for garbage collection to identify an abandoned object.

Comment: Don't forget on a 64bit machine, 32bit drivers are stored separately here:
`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\ODBC\ODBCINST.INI\ODBC Drivers`

Comment: I tried these but not lists the Microsoft Hadoop Hive ODBC Driver

Comment: @Thunder Has the Hadoop driver been installed? Does the bit context of the driver that you installed match the bit context that your code is running under?