# populating data source drivers name in combo box

Tags: c#

I want to populate all available data source drivers in c#. Like ODBC driver, .NET Framework data provider etc. As you can see that in crystal report application all available data sources is displayed when you configure connection with your sql server.

Can we check that whether OleDb driver, ADO.NET driver exist or not using c# code.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6457973/odbc-driver-list-from-net/6458023#6458023

Comment: Is there any comp component which give name of all installed drivers. Like you can see import/export wizard of sql server display all installed drivers.

Answer (score 1):

The example that [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/12kxkt25%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) uses to list ADO.NET providers (for ODBC, check the comment by @HarisHasan):

```
static DataTable GetProviderFactoryClasses()
{
    // Retrieve the installed providers and factories.
    DataTable table = DbProviderFactories.GetFactoryClasses();

    // Display each row and column value.
    foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
    {
        foreach (DataColumn column in table.Columns)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(row[column]);
        }
    }
    return table;
}
```

Comment: Hi,
I had already used this one but this will give not give all data source drivers. It leaves some drivers. Is there is any assembly or com components which give all data source name including .netframework, oledb, odbc etc.