# Specifically how do I access the dialog to create an ODBC datasource via VBA in MSACCESS

Tags: sql-server, vba, ms-access

Please point me in the right direction here. I need to instantiate the dialog that allows a user to select an SQL Server , change/alter authentication and select a database, all which are parts of the create DSN subsystem of ODBC. The application I am writing will need the user to select/create a connections to a desired database. I have seen it used everywhere, but cannot find which libraries are used to do it

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/q/14816607/1188513 - it's C# but the answers on that thread should point you somewhere useful.

Answer (score 0):

As a general rule you don’t need nor want to use the built in dialogs. It is a simple matter to prompt or read in the server name, the database name, and then the user + password for the logon. Once you have this information, then you run some relative simple VBA code to create the links for you.

So in general, the approach to create some linked tables to SQL server does not require one to use the built in dialogs. And once you have some values, you may want to provide code to say switch between production and test – again no ODBC dialog etc. are required.

How to create DSN-less connections and how link to SQL server from code is outlined here:

http://www.accessmvp.com/djsteele/DSNLessLinks.html

Comment: I am beginning to see from my searches that very little info exists on those built in dialog or the odbc dll. I can code the dsn-less connection , but I wanted the user to be able to see sql servers on the network that had the browser service turned on...an earlier answer showed how to invoke the ODBC dialog in C#, but I could not trace where to get the information to retrieve the properties of the control

Comment: Well, you can relative easy do this from .net. So you could write some .net code, convert it to a com object and that would work. There also a activeX example here that should/could work without having to compile or write any code: https://www.codeproject.com/articles/1946/list-sql-servers-on-a-network

Comment: You can list SQL Servers on t4e network using VBA also. The following is old, but still works. http://www.trigeminal.com/code/ServerList.bas

Comment: Albert , AVG ...thanks to both of you, with that information I can make my own control now. Amazed at how something so commonplace in developer products is so poorly documentend on the web. Again thanks !